# Refresh Token with angular and ionic 3 using @ionic/storage

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-http-interceptors

I am implementing my interceptor with refresh token in Angular and ionic using import {Storage} from '@ionic/storage';

I've done the next on my constructor:

```
let getToken = storage.get('TOKEN');
let getTs = storage.get('ts');
let getTypeRegister = storage.get('typeRegister');
let getEmail = storage.get('email');
let getPass = storage.get('password');
Promise.all([getToken, getTs, getTypeRegister, getEmail, getPass]).then(results => {    
  this.token = results[0];
  this.ts = results[1];
  this.typeRegister = results[2];
  this.email = results[3];
  this.password = results[4];
})
```

And my interceptor is :

```
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let getTsObs = Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get('TOKEN'));

    const tokenObservable = getTsObs.map(token => {
      return req = req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
        }
      });
    });
    return tokenObservable.flatMap((req) => {          
      return next.handle(req)
        .do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              // do stuff to the response here                 
            }
          }
          , (err: any) => {
            if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
              if (req.url.search('/auth')) {
                if (err.status === 401) {
                  let newRequest = req.clone({
                    setHeaders: {
                      Accept: `application/json`,
                      'Content-Type': `application/json`
                    }
                  });
                  next.handle(newRequest);
                } else {
                  if (err.status === 403 || err.status === 401) {                       
                    if (this.typeRegister == "loginWithEmail") {                        
                      this._up.loginPhoneObs(this.email, this.password).flatMap(res => {
                        return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.set('TOKEN', res))
                      }).subscribe(res2 => {
                        console.log(res2);                            
                      })
                    }
                    else {                         
                      this._ctp.cleanStorage();
                      let nav = this.app.getActiveNav();
                      nav.setRoot('Login');
                    }

                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        )
 })
 }
```

If the error is by token expired I need to get another token(loginPhoneObs) to save on storage(its a promise) :

```
this._up.loginEmailObs(this.email, this.password).flatMap(res => {
                        return Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.set('TOKEN', res))
                      }).subscribe(res2 => {
                        console.log(res2);
                        console.log('BINGO');
                      })
```

Another solution that I tried is the next, changing error by catch :

```
.catch((res: any) => {
         console.log("ERROR" + res.status + " " + res.error.error);
         if (req.url.search('/auth')) {
           let newRequest = req.clone({
             setHeaders: {
               Accept: `application/json`,
               'Content-Type': `application/json`
             }
           });
           next.handle(newRequest);
         } else {
           if ((res.status === 403) && res.error.error === 'ERR_INVALID_SIGNATURE_OR_CLAIM') {
             return this._up.loginEmailObs(this.email, this.password).flatMap((data: any) => {
               console.log("TOKEN FROM DATA" + data);
               if (data == '') {
                 console.log("TOKEN VACION");
               } else {
                 console.log("TOKEN NO VACION");
                 return Observable.throw(res);
               }
               alert(data);
               let clonedRequestRepeat = req.clone({
                 setHeaders: {
                   Authorization: `Bearer ${data}`
                 }
               });

               return next.handle(clonedRequestRepeat).do(event => {
                 if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                   console.log("Event on Refresh token");
                 }
               })
             })
           } else if (res.status === 400) {
             console.log("ERROR 400");
             return Observable.throw(res);
           } else if (res.status === 401) {
             console.log("ERROR 401");
             return Observable.throw(res);
           } else {
             return Observable.throw(res);
           }
         }
       })
    })
```

In this case, with catch, I dont know where should I do the next:

Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.set('TOKEN', res))

Could someone explain me how can i achive that ?

I've read 2 post :
[Ionic 3 + HttpClientModule and token from storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48097936/ionic-3-httpclientmodule-and-token-from-storage)

[Angular - JWT Refresh Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43930601/angular-jwt-refresh-token)

And the solution using localstorage, my first version is here :

https://github.com/jossephalvarez/ionic-angular-interceptor

Thank you in advance